# How do I make my hover text that also has a background the same size as the icon it is responding to?

Tags: html, css, hover, icons

I have four icons that I each have a text popping up when you hover your mouse over it. The text and the background is just too big when I hover
This is my code

```
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    float:left;
    margin:4px;
    background-size:100%;
    background-position:center;
    transition:0.5s;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow:0 0 4px #000;
  }
 .icons>a:hover{
    background-size:110%;
  } 
.icons>a:before{
  position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
  transform:translateY(100%);
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    color:#fff;
    padding:0 8px;
    content:attr(data-title);
    transition:0.5s 0.1s;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1.5em;
}
  .icons>a:after{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    color:#fff;
    padding:8px;
    content:attr(data-text);
    transition:0.5s;
    padding-top:2em;
    margin-top:8px;
    transform:translateY(100%);
    opacity:0;
  }
.icons>a:hover:after{
    transform:translateY(0);
    transition:0.5s 0.1s;
    opacity:1;
  }
.icons>a:hover:before{
    transform:translateY(0);
    padding:8px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    transition:0.5s;
}
```

This is the relevant html if you are curious:

```
.icons>a{
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    float:left;
    margin:4px;
    background-size:100%;
    background-position:center;
    transition:0.5s;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow:0 0 4px #000;
  }
 .icons>a:hover{
    background-size:110%;
  } 
.icons>a:before{
  position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
  transform:translateY(100%);
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    color:#fff;
    padding:0 8px;
    content:attr(data-title);
    transition:0.5s 0.1s;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1.5em;
}
  .icons>a:after{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    color:#fff;
    padding:8px;
    content:attr(data-text);
    transition:0.5s;
    padding-top:2em;
    margin-top:8px;
    transform:translateY(100%);
    opacity:0;
  }
.icons>a:hover:after{
    transform:translateY(0);
    transition:0.5s 0.1s;
    opacity:1;
  }
.icons>a:hover:before{
    transform:translateY(0);
    padding:8px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    transition:0.5s;
}
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a class="textOverImage" href="#welcome-section" class="textOverImage" data-title="Home"><i class="fas fa-door-open"></i>

  </a>
  
     <a id="projects" href="#projects" class="textOverImage" data-title="Projects"><i class="fas fa-project-diagram"></i>
       
       
  </a>
  
    <a id="contact" href="#contact" class="textOverImage" data-title="Contact"><i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>
      
  </a>
  
      <a id="about" href="#about" data-title="About"><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i>
        
  </a>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: I don't see any hover from your snippet.